# Manifestly confused about VersionOverrides

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

In reference to Outlook Add-in Commands, I am confused about VersionOverrides 1.0 vs 1.1. I see examples with a 1.1 VersionOverrides element embedded in a 1.0 VersionOverrides element in order to get the newer mobileformfactor support, but what is stopping me from replacing schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides with schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1 in my existing desktopformfactor add-in and adding a mobileformfactor entry to that?

Must 1.1 be embedded in 1.0? What would break if 1.0 was swapped out for 1.1? Are some platforms not ready with 1.1 support?

I have searched the web but cannot find good documentation about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...xisting desktopformfactor add-in and adding a mobileformfactor entry to that?

The following resource explains that: [Add support for add-in commands for Outlook Mobile](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/manifests/add-mobile-support?product=outlook)

> Must 1.1 be embedded in 1.0?

Yes.

> What would break if 1.0 was swapped out for 1.1?

You'll get something like this when installing misconfigured manifest: "This app can't be installed. The manifest file doesn't conform to the schema definition."

> Are some platforms not ready with 1.1 support?

Hmmm ... this is weird question. This should be opposite: you, as developer, choose what what manifest version your app needs to support. You need VersionOverrides 1.0, because the child, VersionOverrides 1.1, does not inherit any values from the parent and they have to be there.

> I have searched the web but cannot find good documentation about this.

Here you go: [VersionOverrides element](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/versionoverrides?product=outlook)